# Phone unusable whilst charging

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, charging, clock

I have a fairly old samsung galaxy S2 android 4.1.2. In the last few weeks, it has been behaving really oddly when plugged in to charge. The 'desk clock' page flashes up every few seconds of its own accord, and sometimes the 'voice command' page. When I try to use the phone, I can only operate it for a few seconds at most before one of these things flashes up, which means I have to come out of it and try to get back into what I was doing (usually just for the clock page to come back up again instantly). It's getting worse, to the point I just can't use it when plugged in.

I appreciate the answer is probably eventually going to be to buy a new phone, but was wondering if anyone had any ideas or suggestions in the meantime. Many thanks.

Comment: These are often triggered by magnetic sensors inside the phone. Is there any sort of magnet near the charger? Otherwise, you may have a defective charger or charge port that is tripping these sensors.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your charger's current or voltage is not higher than what your phone is supposed to accept. I had similar issues before with generic (chinese) Android chargers.